# Get all the keys presented in all arrays

Tags: php, associative-array

I have some arrays, for example

```
$arr[0]=array(k1=>1,k2=>1,k3=>1);
$arr[1]=array(k2=>1,k3=>1,k4=>1);
$arr[2]=array(k3=>1,k4=>1,k5=>1);
```

So, I need to get all the keys (dynamically, the number of arrays can differ), presented in all arrays. In this case it is `k3` key. So the result should be `array('k3'=>1)`

I suggest it could be achieved by multiple loops, but probably there's some easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the function [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
<?php

$arr1 = array('k1' => 1, 'k2' => 1, 'k3' => 1);
$arr2 = array('k2' => 1, 'k3' => 1, 'k4' => 1);
$arr3 = array('k3' => 1, 'k4' => 1, 'k5' => 1);

print_r(
    array_intersect_key($arr1, $arr2, $arr3)
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [k3] => 1
)
```

Comment: Yeah that's correct, but how to get them dynamically. I mean there may be any number of arrays. Actually, it's the one multidimentional array.

Comment: @elDude you can use any number of arrays with `array_intersect_key()`, just like I did in my question. If you need to use it on a multi-dimensional array, do something like `call_user_func_array("array_intersect_key", $multiDimArray))`.

Comment: Thanx. Actually that's my fault. I'd better write the question ))

Answer (score 1):

To get the common elements in three arrays, you can use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Note: This function works on **common array values** and not common array **keys**

Try this:

```
$key1 = array_flip($arr1);
$key2 = array_flip($arr1);
$key3 = array_flip($arr1);

$intersect = array_flip(array_intersect($key1, $key2, $key3));
```

Comment: This seems to miss the point of the problem ("all the keys, presented in all arrays," with the desired result `k3`).